# How to properly center an image with ImageMagick to make an icon?

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, icons, imagemagick

Under Windows, using Batch-Script or Powershell, with [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/index.php), I just would like to create a proper icon file like the icons that you can create with [ToyCon](https://www.portablefreeware.com/?id=1792) or [QuickAnyToIco](https://www.carifred.com/quick_any2ico/) programs, that is:

- An icon whose image layer is **centered** in the canvas
- It fits vertical or horizontal edges automatically, that is, the image gets shrinked or enlarged automatically.
- Preserving aspect ratio
- With transparent background
- The icon real size is 256x256px (containing inside the icon other various arbitrary layers of typical sizes: 128x128, 64x64, 32x32, 16x16 etc)

That is a simple task that any conventional icon converter software for Windows will do perfectly.

---

Now, using **ImageMagick**, the `icon:auto-resize` argument it is not of any help, because it stretches the image to fit width and height.

I've read **ImageMagick's** documentation and it has these two modifiers:

- ['>' flag: Only Shrink Larger Images](https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/#shrink)
- ['<' flag: Only Enlarge Smaller Images](https://Only%20Enlarge%20Smaller%20Images%20(%27%3C%27%20flag))

I noticed they can be specified in both the width and height values specified in both `-resize` and `-extent` arguments.

And this:

- ['^': Fill Given Area](https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/#fill)

...for `-extent` argument.

But I can't find the way to use or combine them properly to center the image by shrinking and enlarging - preserving aspect ratio - automatically to fit width or height. Just like [QuickAnyToIco](https://www.carifred.com/quick_any2ico/) program does, I insist.

---

This is a sample command that I try to create a 256x256 png layer for the icon:

Input image size: 513x458

Command is this:

```
Magick.exe convert "image.jpg" -resize "256>x256" -background white -gravity center -extent "256^x256^" -quality 100 "output.png"
```

And the resulting output image is this:

[image]

OUTPUT IS OK !!, that is the same result as produced by any good icon converter software.

Now, using the same command with an image size of 208x242, I get this resulting output image:

[image]

OUTPUT IS WRONG !!. Image is centered but top and bottom edges does not fit.

I expect this resulting image (produced by any good icon converter software):

[image]

And I can achieve it using this command:

```
Magick.exe convert "cover.jpg" -resize "256<x256" -background white -gravity center -extent "256^x256^" -quality 100 "output.png"
```

But it only works for smaller images like that one. That same command will produce this other image:

[image]

---

NOTES:

- The white background is just a convenience color that I chose for better visual presentation of the problem.
- Original input images used in the examples above:

  ```
  https://i.imgur.com/wiXntuD.jpg

  https://i.imgur.com/QaWV1Oe.jpg
  ```

Comment: Only one special symbol is needed at the end of the argument values. So you do not need to have two ^ in your command.  Have you tried both > and < in the same argument?  Your "Gameboy" image has a white border. Did you know that and take that into account? In IM 7, use magick.exe not magick.exe convert.

Comment: Or remove your < character and try that.

Comment: @fmw42 Yes I have tried the "><" combination (and more) like for example: "256x256><", with and without the "convert" argument, it does not shrink larger images. Removing the "<" modifier will not solve the problem to do proper image resize with the two scenery cases (the two example images that I shown). The white background is just a convenience color that I chose for better visual presentation of the problem in my post. Thanks for the commentaries.

Comment: Did you try leaving off both > and <?  I am not sure I understand what you want and you did not post all the input image in your example outputs.

Comment: @fmw42 Buddy, I probably don't know how to explain it in the clearest way possible, but trying to make it simple: in essence I'm looking to mimic the same image resizing logic that any good icon converter program uses, and I put as reference QuickAnyToIco. Any image you convert to an icon with that program, I hope to obtain the same results (the image centered in the same proper way) when automating the icon conversion with ImageMagick. Because that resizing logic (from QuickAnyToIco or from any other good converter) is what is expected when converting an image to ico.

Comment: And I shared the two input images used in the examples. One for the "Diablo" cover, and the other japanese game cover.

Comment: You only show the output of both diablo images, if your text above it is correct, but not the input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With ImageMagick v7 on Windows 11, I use this command to make icons from nearly any input image...

```
magick image.jpg -gravity center -extent 1:1# ^
   -define icon:auto-resize="256,128,64,48,32,24,16" result.ico
```

It starts with "-extent 1:1#" to extend the input image's canvas to a 1:1 ratio. The "#" flag tells it to add canvas as needed to achieve the 1:1 ratio.

The command continues with that square image, and using IM's icon sizing define, it will output an icon containing the sizes specified.

Comment: It's just the resizing logic I expected, solved in the most direct and simple way that I can imagine!. I know that I have not been able to explain the problem in the most understandable way possible, so thank you very much for understanding my problem.

Comment: The "#" flag is relatively new, and may not be described in some of the available help material. Previously I would use "-resize WxH -extent WxH". Resizing with no flags keeps the aspect and fits the image inside the specified dimensions. Then extending the canvas just adds whatever is needed to the short dimensions.

Comment: Using your syntax example, if I add a "-quality 100" argument it seems to have no effect (I tried -quality 5 too to see if it generates worse images, but the result seems the same). Can I do something about that?.

Comment: I'm not familiar with how "-quality" options affect icon output. That might be a subject for another discussion. Bring example images and commands.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I could come up with to solve this, is a scripted solution to get and evaluate the width and height of the input image, and then decide whether to use the "`<`" or "`>`" flag in the **magick.exe** arguments.

So, this is a **PowerShell** script that will search recursively for bmp, jpeg/jpg, png, and webp files, and convert them to ico. It seems to work as expected, centering the image and shrinking or enlarging to fit the nearest canvas edges while preserving aspect ratio.

```
$imageMagickFullPath = "C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.1.1-Q8\magick.exe"

$exts = @('.bmp', '.jpeg', '.jpg', '.png', '.webp')
$files = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath (Get-Location) -Filter "*.*" -Recurse | Where-Object { $exts -contains $_.Extension.ToLower() }
$tempDir = [System.IO.Path]::GetTempPath()

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

foreach ($file in $files) {
    Write-Host "Converting to icon: $($file.FullName)"

    $fileName = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($file.Name)
    $outIconFilePath = $file.Directory.FullName + "\" + $fileName + ".ico"
    $layerFilePaths = @()

    $image  = [System.Drawing.Image]::FromFile($file.FullName)
    $width  = $image.Width
    $height = $image.Height
    $image.Dispose()

    # Create icon layers.
    $sizes = @(256, 128, 96, 64, 32, 24, 16)
    foreach ($size in $sizes) {
        $layerFilePath = Join-Path -Path $tempDir -ChildPath "icon_layer-$sizex$size.png"
        $layerFilePaths += $layerFilePath

        if ($width -gt $size) {
            $args = "convert `"$($file.FullName)`" -resize $size>x$size -background transparent -gravity center -extent $size^x$size^ -quality 100 `"$layerFilePath`""
        } elseif ($width -le $size) {
            if ($height -lt $size) {
                $args = "convert `"$($file.FullName)`" -resize $size<x$size -background transparent -gravity center -extent $size^x$size^ -quality 100 `"$layerFilePath`""
            } elseif ($height -gt $size) {
                $args = "convert `"$($file.FullName)`" -resize $size>x$size -background transparent -gravity center -extent $size^x$size^ -quality 100 `"$layerFilePath`""
            } else { # ($height -eq $size)
                $args = "convert `"$($file.FullName)`" -resize       x$size -background transparent -gravity center -extent $size^x$size^ -quality 100 `"$layerFilePath`""
            }
        }

        $procStartInfo = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
        $procStartInfo.FileName = $imageMagickFullPath
        $procStartInfo.Arguments = $args
        $procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = $false
        $process = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process
        $process.StartInfo = $procStartInfo
        $process.Start() | Out-Null
        $process.WaitForExit()
    }

    # Combine layers to create the icon file.
    $procStartInfo = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
    $procStartInfo.FileName = $imageMagickFullPath
    $procStartInfo.Arguments = (($layerFilePaths | ForEach-Object { "`"$_`"" }) -join ' ') + " " + "`"$outIconFilePath`""
    $procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = $false
    $process = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process
    $process.StartInfo = $procStartInfo
    $process.Start() | Out-Null
    $process.WaitForExit()
}

Write-Host "operation Completed."
Write-Host ""
Write-Host "Press any key to exit..."
[System.Console]::ReadKey($true)
Exit(0)
```

---

The most important and relevant part of the code above is this conditional block:

```
if ($width -gt $size) {
    $args = "convert `"$($file.FullName)`" -resize $size>x$size -background transparent -gravity center -extent $size^x$size^ -quality 100 `"$layerFilePath`""
} elseif ($width -le $size) {
    if ($height -lt $size) {
        $args = "convert `"$($file.FullName)`" -resize $size<x$size -background transparent -gravity center -extent $size^x$size^ -quality 100 `"$layerFilePath`""
    } elseif ($height -gt $size) {
        $args = "convert `"$($file.FullName)`" -resize $size>x$size -background transparent -gravity center -extent $size^x$size^ -quality 100 `"$layerFilePath`""
    } else { # ($height -eq $size)
        $args = "convert `"$($file.FullName)`" -resize       x$size -background transparent -gravity center -extent $size^x$size^ -quality 100 `"$layerFilePath`""
    }
}
```

---

### UPDATE:

[@GeeMack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77643103/1248295)'s solution using PowerShell:

```
$magickFilePath = "C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-7.1.1-Q8\magick.exe"

$magickArgs = @('-define icon:auto-resize="256,128,96,64,48,32,24,16"',
                '-background transparent',
                '-gravity center',
                '-extent 1:1#', 
                '-quality 100'
               )

$exts = @('.bmp', '.jpeg', '.jpg', '.png', '.webp')
$files = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath (Get-Location) -Filter "*.*" -Recurse | Where-Object { $exts -contains $_.Extension.ToLower() }

foreach ($file in $files) {
    Write-Host "Converting to icon: $($file.FullName)"

    $fileName = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($file.Name)
    $outIconFilePath = $file.Directory.FullName + "\" + $fileName + ".ico"

    $procStartInfo = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
    $procStartInfo.FileName = $magickFilePath
    $procStartInfo.Arguments = "`"$($file.FullName)`" $($magickArgs -join ' ') `"$outIconFilePath`""
    $procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = $false
    $process = New-Object System.Diagnostics.Process
    $process.StartInfo = $procStartInfo
    $process.Start() | Out-Null
    $process.WaitForExit()
}

Write-Host "operation Completed."
Write-Host ""
Write-Host "Press any key to exit..."
[System.Console]::ReadKey($true)
Exit(0)
```